# Drive-by downvoted out of a privilege

Tags: discussion, reputation, down-votes, privileges

I just hit 10k rep earlier today and was exploring the mod tools when I noticed they had...  disappeared.  I checked my [recent rep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17875/eevee?tab=reputation) and it looks suspiciously like someone downvoted just enough of my answers to knock me down to 9999.  The answers have wildly different timestamps, subjects, quality, and existing votes, yet eight were downvoted within the span of two minutes.

-16 isn't a huge deal or anything, but I'm morbidly curious: is this a known phenomenon, to be downvoted out of a privilege?  I don't have any mortal enemies on SO, as far as I know, so I can only assume this is random (though I checked a few other users who just passed 10k and they escaped unscathed).

Comment: Yep. Serial downvoting. This will most likely be reversed by the system. Give it a day at most.

Comment: It should be reversed automatically if it is serial downvoting. Probably someone wants to play a prank on you.

Comment: wow, i had no idea this was automatically detected.  impressive!  thanks guys  :)

Comment: See the power of the meta, You are already back on track.

Comment: It's my immortal enemies I worry about.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment Why? They just wait until you reach 20K.